# Stop redirection to https using nginx and symfony

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have this config :

```
server {
server_name api.myhost.com www.api.myhost.com;
root /var/www/host/symfony/public;
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

error_page 401 403 404 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
location / {
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
}

location @rewriteapp { rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last; }

location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
}

location ~ ^/.*\.(css|js|jpe?g|png|ico)$ {
    expires 7d;
}

error_log /var/log/nginx/host.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/host.log;

}
```

When I try to access http://api.myhost.com/login. I have an form, but when I try to submit my form I'm redirected to https://api.myhost.com/login, and I have the error in browser : The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments. Can you help me please ? How I can disable this redirect to https. Thx in advance and sorry for my english.

Any ideas please ?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your config looks fine, I guess this is browser hsts cache issue.

Try going to: chrome://net-internals/#hsts, delete the policy for your "myhost.com".

Clear cache and cookies for your site and restart the browser.